What exactly does the "formal" in "formal markedness" refer to?
A paper I am currently reading (Mollin 2012) mentions formal markedness as an ordering constraint for binomials in English. At first I thought that formal just means that the form of the word is altered, as with pre- or suffixation (lion->lioness, or visible->invisible), but Mollin writes:

In practice, the formal markedness constraint serves to predict the binomial order of
near-synonymous pairs. BNC examples include: tried and tested, rules and regulations
and health and fitness (p. 88).

After reading up on it, I'm even more confused than before. Battistella (1990) contains the following table (on p. 34) to illustrate formal markedness:




Unmarked
Marked




a.
host
hostess


b.
go
goes


c.
cat
cats


d.
possible
impossible


e.
see
sees



That would fit. However, Benor & Levi (2006) write, citing Battistella:

"Criteria for lower formal markedness. Less marked items tend to: a. have a broader, more general meaning
b. have greater freedom of distribution
c. have a larger number of subcategorical distinctions
d. be structurally more simple (p. 237)

To me it seems that only d. actually describes formal markedness as it is used by Battistella. Would appreciate it if anyone who is familiar with the term could give me an explanation of what is going on here. Thanks in advance.
Battistella, Edwin. 1990. Markedness: The evaluative superstructure of language. Albany: State University of New York Press.
Benor, Sarah Bunin & Robert Levy. 2006. The chicken or the egg? A probabilistic analysis of English binomials. Language 82, 233–77.
Mollin, Sandra. 2012. Revisiting binomial order in English: ordering constraints and reversibility. ELL 16.1: 81–103.
